# Azure Maps map rotation aligned label on top of extruded polygon

Tags: azure-maps

Is it possible to create an elevated non-rotating label on top of an extruded polygon inside Azure Maps?

For context, labels can either rotate together with the camera view (picture 1; rotation aligned with camera), or stay in the same rotation (picture 2; rotation aligned with map):

[image]    [image]

A polygon can be extruded to create a 3D look:

[image]

Is it possible to create a symbol layer that shows a label, rotation aligned with the map (such as in the second label picture), but on top of the extruded polygon, as if the label is printed on there? For example, let's say that I create an extruded polygon of height 2 and base 0. I would then want to be able to place a label on height 2, such that it shows as if it's on top of the polygon.

I've looked at all the Azure Maps samples and didn't find such a feature, so it might not exist, or I might've looked over something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, there isn't a good way to do this. The closest would be to lock the rotation the map and set the pitch to the viewport in the Symbol layer options.

```js
{
    textOptions: {
        textField: [
            "get",
            "title"
        ],
        pitchAlignment: "viewport",
        rotationAlignment: "map"
    }
}
```

You might be able to get close to what you are looking for by adjusting the symbol layers rotation as the map moves.

For #2, there is no option to set the elevation of a symbol. The closest you could do is adjust the y offset value as the maps pitch adjust.

This is a good sample to try the different options of the symbol layer out: https://samples.azuremaps.com/symbol-layer/symbol-layer-options

Comment: What do you mean exactly with #1? My question was only about the elevation of the symbol, the map rotation was achieved using the 'map' setting on the 'rotationAlignment' property. But thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought you were asking how to get the labels to appear upright and rotate in alignment with a path on the map.